# React Native Reanimated: com.swmansion.reanimated.nodes.NoopNode cannot be cast to com.swmansion.reanimated.nodes.ClockNode

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I created a react native component called SwipeRow that I want to use to remove elements from a Flatlist with a swipe gesture and nice animation, however when I swipe or touch my component i get this error:

```
com.swmansion.reanimated.nodes.NoopNode cannot be cast to com.swmansion.reanimated.nodes.ClockNode.
```

My package.json

```
"react-native-reanimated": "^2.8.0",
```

This is my component:

```
import {
    PanGestureHandler,
    State as GestureState,
  } from 'react-native-gesture-handler';
  import Animated from 'react-native-reanimated';
  const {
    event,
    cond,
    Value,
    block,
    set,
    eq,
    not,
    clockRunning,
    and,
    startClock,
    stopClock,
    spring,
    greaterThan,
    lessThan,
    call,
    Clock,
  } = Animated;


export default SwipeRow = observer((props) => 
{

    
    
    //const [ user, setUser ] = useState(false);
    const root = useStore();
    const navigation = useNavigation();
    const { children } = props;
    const { t } = useTranslation();



    const clock = new Clock();
    
    const gestureState = new Value(GestureState.UNDETERMINED);
    const animState = {
    finished: new Value(0),
    position: new Value(0),
    velocity: new Value(0),
    time: new Value(0),
    };


    // Spring animation config
    // Determines how "springy" row is when it
    // snaps back into place after released
    const animConfig = {
    toValue: new Value(0),
    damping: 20,
    mass: 0.2,
    stiffness: 100,
    overshootClamping: false,
    restSpeedThreshold: 0.2,
    restDisplacementThreshold: 0.2,
    };
  

    // Called whenever gesture state changes. (User begins/ends pan,
  // or if the gesture is cancelled/fails for some reason)
    const onHandlerStateChange = event([
    {
      nativeEvent: ({ state }) =>
        block([
          // Update our animated value that tracks gesture state
          set(gestureState, state),
          // Spring row back into place when user lifts their finger before reaching threshold
          cond(
            and(eq(state, GestureState.END), not(clockRunning(clock))),
            startClock(clock)
          ),
        ]),
    },
  ]);

    const onPanEvent = event([
    {
      nativeEvent: ({ translationX }) =>
        block([
          cond(eq(gestureState, GestureState.ACTIVE), [
            // Update our translate animated value as the user pans
            set(animState.position, translationX),
            // If swipe distance exceeds threshold, delete item
            cond(
              lessThan(translationX, props.swipeThreshold),
              call([animState.position], () =>
                props.onSwipe(props.item)
              )
            ),
          ]),
        ]),
    },
  ]);

   

    return (

        <PanGestureHandler
        minDeltaX={10}
        onGestureEvent={onPanEvent}
        onHandlerStateChange={onHandlerStateChange}>
        <Animated.View
          style={{
            flex: 1,
            transform: [{ translateX: animState.position }],
          }}>
          <Animated.Code>
            {() =>
              block([
                // If the clock is running, increment position in next tick by calling spring()
                cond(clockRunning(clock), [
                  spring(clock, animState, animConfig),
                  // Stop and reset clock when spring is complete
                  cond(animState.finished, [
                    stopClock(clock),
                    set(animState.finished, 0),
                  ]),
                ]),
              ])
            }
          </Animated.Code>
          {children}
        </Animated.View>
      </PanGestureHandler>

       
    );

});
```